# Python NetCDF bounds lat lng in 4 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, netcdf

I'm trying to extract a spatial subset in my netCDF file. I'm using numpy and NetCDF4 Python library.

My data are in the `pm10_conc` variable and they look like this -> [image](https://i.imgsafe.org/5691582954.png)

**pm10_conc is built with time, level, latitude, longitude**

- Time is a number from 1 to 24 (it's the hours)
- Level is always 0 in my case for the moment.

For testing, I want to get the data :

```
Latitude  -> from 69.95 to 69.85
Longitude -> from 335.05 to 335.25
```

Then if you look my [image](https://i.imgsafe.org/5691582954.png) this will returns me :

```
69.95, 335.05 = 0.122270
69.95, 335.15 = 0.122270
69.95, 335.25 = 0.122015

69.85, 335.05 = 0.133071
69.85, 335.15 = 0.122697
69.85, 335.25 = 0.120764
```

So here is my python script :

```
import netCDF4
import json
import numpy

data = netCDF4.Dataset('Data.nc')

latbounds = [ 69.95 , 69.85 ]
lonbounds = [ 335.05 , 335.25 ]
lats = data.variables['latitude'][:]
lons = data.variables['longitude'][:]

level = data.variables['level'][:] # Not used in my code
time = data.variables['time'][:]   # Not used in my code

# latitude lower and upper index
latli = numpy.argmin( numpy.abs( lats - latbounds[0] ) )
latui = numpy.argmin( numpy.abs( lats - latbounds[1] ) )

# longitude lower and upper index
lonli = numpy.argmin( numpy.abs( lons - lonbounds[0] ) )
lonui = numpy.argmin( numpy.abs( lons - lonbounds[1] ) )

pm10 = data.variables['pm10_conc'][ : , : , latli:latui , lonli:lonui ]

print pm10
```

But this will returns me all data in the 24 hours of the first cell (`69.95, 335.05`)

How can I make my bounds work and how can I choose the value of the time (E.g : if I want the data when time is 5 )?

Comment: The slicing based on lat/lon seems to be correct; if the dimensions are `time, level, latitude, longitude`, writing `[5,0,latli:latui,lonli:lonui]` should give you a 2D array with the results from `time`=5 and `level`=0?

Comment: @John  I agree. For the future you should post an answer which could be accepted.